# How to use Bash parameter substitution in a Makefile?

Tags: bash, shell, makefile, syntax, string-substitution

I've the following `Makefile` where I'd like to use [Bash parameter substitution](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html) syntax as below:

```
SHELL:=/bin/bash
Foo=Bar
all:
  @echo ${Foo}
  @echo ${Foo/Bar/OK}
```

However it doesn't work as expected, as the output of the second `echo` command is empty:

```
$ make
Bar
(empty)
```

Although it works fine when invoking in shell directly:

```
$ Foo=Bar; echo ${Foo/Bar/OK}
OK
```

How can I use the above syntax in Makefile?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you want the shell to expand the variable you have to use a shell variable, not a make variable.  `${Foo/Bar/OK}` is a make variable named literally `Foo/Bar/OK`.

If you want to use shell variable substitution you'll have to assign that value to a shell variable:

```
all:
        Foo='$(Foo)'; echo $${Foo/Bar/OK}
```

Note that we use the double-dollar `$$` to escape the dollar sign so that make doesn't try to expand it.

I *strongly* recommend you don't add `@` to your rules until you're sure they work.  It's the single most common mistake I see; if people would just not use `@` they could see the command make is invoking, and then they would better understand how make works.