# Why parameter expansion does not work in Makefile?

Tags: bash, makefile, parameter-expansion

I have next rule in `Makefile`:

```
dbrestoretable:
    echo ${TABLE:-asdf}
```

When I run:

```
$ make dbrestoretable 
echo
```

But:

```
$ echo ${TABLE:-asdf}
asdf
```

Why *default value* `asdf` is not echoed in first case?

**UPD**

Specified [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42462115/how-to-use-bash-parameter-substitution-in-a-makefile) speaks about how to use variable assigned in `Makefile`. And it does not answer why default value is not used

Look at this modified example:

```
dbrestoretable:
    echo ${TABLE:-asdf}
    echo ${TABLE}
```

Then run:

```
$ make dbrestoretable TABLE=mytable
echo 
echo mytable

$ make dbrestoretable
echo 
echo
```

As you can see when I use `${TABLE:-asdf}` it just return empty string. But I expect in first run `mytable` and second run `asdf` value to be echoed

Comment: Actually it does tell you: the first `$` is expanded by make, not shell. Both `${name:-default}` and `${name/match/replace}` are implemented by shells (the latter only some shells) and not by make. To have shell do the expansion, you must use `$$` to tell make to send `$` to shell.