# make split string get last element

Tags: string, bash, makefile, split, gnu-make

In bash I can split a string similar to
[How to split a string in shell and get the last field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3162385/how-to-split-a-string-in-shell-and-get-the-last-field)

```
foo=1:2:3:4:5
echo ${foo##*:}
```

how can I achieve something similar with make inside a makefile? Any solutions I found were a lot more complicated than the bash pendant.

I tried to use:
`$(shell ${foo##*:})` but this fails as a string does not seem to terminate properly.

Comment: is it a string or a variable inside the makefile? If it's a variable, then you can source the file and echo the variable.  Please explain in bit more detail and give an example of the makefile section you're referring to. Also, do you want to change that file or just use the output somehow?

Comment: I just want to use the output. The variable is passed when calling the makefile , i.e. `make myvar=my/value/last.thing mytask`

Comment: @GeorgHeiler So, it is a make variable, not a shell variable. In your example `echo $(lastword $(subst /, ,$(myvar)))` does what you want (see my answer for a detailed explanation).

Comment: May I ask if you also find [these functions](https://github.com/markpiffer/gmtt#call-glob-matchstringpattern) too complicated to consider?

Comment: see the accepted answer - no

Comment: Um, I think you missed the link to https://github.com/markpiffer/gmtt#call-glob-matchstringpattern in my question?

Comment: Indeed, that also looks good.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### If `foo` is a make variable

From the [Text functions section](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Text-Functions) of the [GNU make manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html):

> `$(subst from,to,text)` performs a textual replacement on the text
>   *text*: each occurrence of *from* is replaced by *to*. The result is
>   substituted for the function call.

So:

```
$(subst :, ,$(foo))
```

splits the content of make variable `foo` by replacing all `:` by a space. Still from GNU make manual:

> `$(lastword names…)` The argument *names* is regarded as a series of
>   names, separated by whitespace. The value is the last name in the
>   series.

So:

```
$(lastword $(subst :, ,$(foo)))
```

should do what you want. Demo (`host>` is the shell prompt):

```
host> cat Makefile
foo := 1:2:3:4:5

all:
    $(info $(lastword $(subst :, ,$(foo))))
host> make
5
```

#### If `foo` is a shell variable

You must:

1. Protect the `$` signs of your recipe from the first expansion that make performs before passing the recipe to the shell,
2. Consider that each line of your recipe is executed by a separate shell: if you define a shell variable on a line and use it on another one, it does not work as you would expect.

```
all:
    @foo=1:2:3:4:5 && \
    echo $${foo##*:}
```

should do what you want: the `$` sign is properly escaped and it is a single-line recipe (thanks to the trailing `\`). Demo:

```
host> cat Makefile
all:
    @foo=1:2:3:4:5 && \
    echo $${foo##*:}
host> make
5
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use a [double dollar symbol](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42462357/469210) you'll escape the dollar which can then be passed along to the shell.

e.g. `echo $${foo##*.}` inside your `makefile`.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is `GNU make`-releated but I want to show how simple is in `BSD make`:

```
FOO=1:2:3:4:5

all:
    @echo ${FOO:C/.*://}
```

And the test:

```
$ make
5
```

Explanation ([man make](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=make&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD%2011.2-RELEASE%20and%20Ports&arch=default&format=html)): the `:C...` in `${FOO:C/.*://}` named *Variable modifier*. The `:C` modifier works like `sed`'s `s` command. in this case it changes all *word* in variable `${FOO}` defined by `sed`-like expression: all character and the trailing colon replaced to nothing (aka delete it).

Please note that the `.*:` expression is greedy (as usual - the `.*` can contain many colons).